# E-mail if run out of space on jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anybody knows a plugin for Jenkins Continuous Integration that send an e-mail when I ran out of space on master PC or alerts me via e-mail if I'm having a low space on master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the latest `Jenkins disk-usage plugin`. In the Jenkin configuration page under the tab `Disk Usage` >> `Warn if some size is exceeded` you need to mention the threshold disk usage and the Email address details as shown below.

[image]

Comment: seems like disk usage plugin no longer has email support - or am Iooking in the wrong place?

Comment: The configuration is located at "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" at SECTION "Disk usage" i.e. right hand side.

The Jenkins Configure page is usually quite long, use browser's search to locate it.

Comment: Does not work anymore in latest Jenkins. Also there seems that no plugin is available anymore that has this function.